# how can I add api_key in logstash conf file for sending data?

Tags: rest, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I want to send the rest API data to Elasticsearch from logstash. But I don't know how I can API URL and API key to logstash conf file.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fq7tC.jpg)

Here  I am sharing my logstash conf file.

Answer (score 0):

You required to set `Authorization` header for api key like below:

```json
input {
  http_poller {
    urls => {
      test1 => {
        method => get
        url => "https://my-api-url"
        headers => {
          Accept => "application/json"
          Authorization => "Basic ZWxhc3RpY"
        }
     }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: update your question with your configuration and error logs.

Comment: Failed to execute action {:action=>LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:main, :exception=>"LogStash::ConfigurationError", :message=>"Expected one of [A-Za-z0-9_], [ \\t\\r\\n], \"#\", \"=>\" at line 4, column 9 (byte 50) after input {\r\n  http_poller {\r\n    urls => {\r\n      my", :backtrace=>["C:/Users/Rinki/Documents/electosearch/logstash-8.1.2-windows-x86_64/logstash-8.1.2/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:32:in `compile_imperative'", "org/logstash/execution/AbstractPipelineExt.java:189:in `initialize'", "org/logstash/execution/JavaBasePipelineExt.java:72:in `initialize'",

Comment: put yoru configuration in question with proper format so it will easy for us to help.

Comment: Error is occuring because of `my-api-poller` so just replace name with `test` and try it.

Comment: An unexpected error occurred! {:error=>#<LogStash::Error: Don't know how to handle Java::JavaLang::IllegalStateException for PipelineAction::Create<main>>, :backtrace=>["org/logstash/execution/ConvergeResultExt.java:135:in create'", "org/logstash/execution/ConvergeResultExt.java:60:in add'"

Comment: input {
  http_poller {
    urls => {
      test => {
        method => get
        url => ""
        headers => {
          Accept => "application/json"
          Authorization => ""
        }
     }
    }
  }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
   hosts => ["localhost:9200"] 
   index => "logstash_ind"
 }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
this is my conf file